# MySQL: I cannot login as root after upgrading to 5.5

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.ovaistariq.net/490/a-step-by-step-guide-to-upgrading-to-mysql-5-5/) to upgrade to mysql 5.5.

After finishing all the steps I do `$ mysql -u root -pXXXX` and it says:

```
Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

The tutorial worked for me sometime ago, but now I have this problem. I have reinstalled ubuntu+mysql 5.1 and I have no problem doing "mysql -u root -pXXXX", but after upgrading to 5.5 I get again the error above..

This is my /etc/my.cnf:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password    = your_password
port        = 3306
socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir         = /usr/local/mysql
datadir         = /usr/local/mysql/data
tmpdir          = /tmp
log_error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
skip-external-locking
...
```

Any idea?

**EDIT:** solved, well.. I just should do a backup of the user 'root' since I'm removing the database before upgrading to 5.5.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just saying that you're using the wrong password really...

Maybe you have to reset the root password, though I wouldn't know why (maybe the updater overwrote it?), here's the procedure:

1. make sure there are no mysqld deamons running.
2. get to your mysql/bin directory
3. start a mysql deamon with `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` (note the PID)
4. start command line mysql: `mysql`
5. execute this little script with your edit:

[code]
    use `mysql`;
    UPDATE `user` SET `Password`=PASSWORD('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD_HERE') WHERE `User` = 'root';
    exit;
[/code]

Now you're only need to kill your `mysqld_safe` (remember the PID?..) and start the deamon normally.

Comment: thanks but the root user has dissapeared. I'm looking for information to create a new one but I dont find anything..any idea?

Comment: that's really odd. you could issue a command: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-password-here';` while in the safe mysql shell.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04, as root user:

```
# service mysql stop
# mkdir /etc/run/mysql && chown -R mysql:mysql /etc/run/mysql
# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql &
```

This will start mysql without validating root user. Then, in another terminal/ssh window, you can start mysql client and change the root user password:

```
# mysql -u root
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('NeWPaSSWoRD') WHERE User = 'root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;
```

Then, stop the mysqld_safe process in the first terminal. Replace the "processid" below with the contents of /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pin.

```
# kill -9 "processid"
```

Start mysql and try logging in again.

```
# service mysql start
# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log (Ubuntu)
mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself of a MAJOR headache... Your problem might be that you are missing the quotes around the password. Specially because you can actually login passing the -p switch and not using your .my.cnf.

```
[client]
user = myusername
password = "mypassword"
host = localhost
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html

Answer (score 0):

RE: CENTOS

Make sure you have set mysql to auto-start on boot:

> chkconfig --list mysqld

If not, then add mysql to startup script:

> chkconfig --levels 345 mysqld on

...and reboot.

If that still does not work, this did the trick for me:

> /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
>
> mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
>
> mysql -u root
>
> mysql> use mysql;
>
> mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("newrootpassword") where User='root';
>
> mysql> flush privileges;
>
> mysql> quit
>
> /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
>
> /etc/init.d/mysqld start